# Regular Expression finding specific instances

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble finding a regular expression for the following problem

All strings over the alphabet {a, b, c, d} with at least four instances of c and at least two instances of a

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? Just count the occurences.

Comment: I guess this is some kind of homework? If so I guess you want a "proper" regular expression that only can describe regular languages, and not the kind of regexen that contains extension that allow them to create non-regular langaues. If so please make sure you state that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a look-ahead:

```
^(?=(.*c){4,})(?=(.*a){2,})[a-z]+
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "alphabet" - I have assumed "any letter", but if it's literally a,b,c and d, change `[a-z]+` to `[a-d]+`

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to work with this test case?    cbdbdbdbdbcbdbdbdbdbcdbdbdbdbcdbdbbdbdcdbdbdbdbcdbdbdbcdbdbcdbcdbadbad

Comment: Lookaheads are not proper regular expressions, though, so if this is homework, your professor probably wants you to discover that you have to enumerate all the possible permutations.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know why you would say that lookaheads are not considered "proper regular expressions". They are supported in every language I can think of.

Comment: Because in a strict mathematical sense, the concept of lookaheads extends the expressive power of the formalism beyond that of regular sets. The use if a restricted, symbolic alphabet certainly suggests that the question relates to the theory of computation, rather than to any real-world implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more efficient than Bohemian's solution, and also anchored to make sure we don't just match a substring of a longer string that might contain unwanted characters:

```
^(?=(?:[^c]*c){4})(?=(?:[^a]*a){2})[a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in comments, this question seems to relate to the strict mathematical theory of regular expressions as derived from set theory. In that case, lookaheads are not permitted; you need to enumerate the permitted sequences. For simplicity and clarity, I am omitting the `.*` which should go before, between, and after the symbols in the following list.

```
ccccaa|
cccaca|
cccaac|
ccacca|
ccacac|
ccacca|
ccaacc|
caccca|
caccac|
cacacc|
caaccc|
acccca|
acccac|
accacc|
acaccc|
aacccc
```